# Import excel and csv files one at a time on servicestack

Tags: c#-4.0, queue, task-parallel-library, blockingcollection

We have an ASP.NET MVC web application and here's the requirement:

Users should be able to import excel/csv files to the system but they must be imported one at a time (First In First Out) but allow users to upload as many files as they want and system will process all files and import them in the same order of its loading.

How can I use C# TPL and BlockingCollection to achieve this feature?
I think the producer/consumer pattern can be used to queue files using BlockingCollection and dequeue the files through the consumer. But, where should the producer and consumer be declared and defined? Would this be in the global.asax application start event? Another requirement is we need to maintain one queue per client as it is a multi-tenant application.